# Open circuit volts and short circuit amps

Tags: solar-cell

I am looking to buy a few solar cells to mess around and learn with and I don't understand what exactly this part in the description is telling me:

"...offering 4.5V (open circuit) and 18mA (short circuit)"

Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Open-circuit voltage` is the maximum output voltage with no load applied.

`short-circuit current` is the maximum output current with 0 ohm load.

Assuming the V-I curve (graph of voltage output vs current output) is linear, then the source impedance is 4.5V / 18mA = 250ohms. In other words, this solar cell behaves like a 4.5V battery with 250 ohms in series. This source impedance is not a real resistor component, but a characteristic of the physical voltage source. When you model its behavior, you model it as though it were a Thevenin voltage source of 4.5V in series with 250 ohms.

At the extreme of open-circuit, the load current is 0mA and therefore the power transfer is 0 watts.

At the other extreme of short-circuit, the voltage provided to the load is 0V and therefore the power transfer is 0 watts.

To get maximum power transfer, the load impedance needs to be matched to the source impedance. (If you could choose the source impedance you'd obviously choose 0 ohms, but that's not possible.) If the load is 250 ohms and the source impedance is 250 ohms, then the power transfer will be 2.25V x 9mA = 20mW (assuming linear V-I curve).

In reality, the V-I curve is probably not linear, but without more data it's probably good enough for initial estimates. If you're trying to get 10-15mW that should be possible, but you won't get more than 20mW out of this solar panel.

Comment: Note too that the effective impedance varies depending on light input, which is why you have 'maximum power point tracking' (MPPT) hardware designed to get maximum power out of a solar panel.

Answer (score 2):

It means what it says: if you have the cell unconnected driving nothing, there will be up to 4.5V across the terminals. If you connect the terminals together through an ammeter, it will read 18ma. There will be some sort of standard assumption about the light on the cell during these measurements.

This does *not* mean you can get 18ma at 4.5V; drawing current reduces the voltage at the terminals. There will be an optimal level that maximises the power delivered by the cell, and this is what a Maximum Power Point Tracker (MPPT) is for in large PV installations.

The actual power to be expected should be quoted separately in watts.

Answer (score 2):

It means if you were to measure the voltage across the leads coming from the solar cell with a multimeter with no load on them the voltage would be 4.5v.

If you were to connect the two leads to your multimeter in a current mode, essentially shorting them, it would read 18 mA.  So this is the theoretical maximum current the solar cell can output (in practice, it will be lower).